# Android:Take pictures to send them with WebService

Tags: android

I want to take a number of photos and, when completing , send all of them on an WebService without keeping them on the device.

I already tried deleting them after sending but I didn't succeed.

What is the best way to do this?

This is my image capturing activity.

```
private ImageView imgPreview;
private Button btnCapturePicture;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_capture);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
    btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);

    /**
     * Capture image button click event
     * */
    btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
    });

}


GPSTracker gps;
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        //TODO
        gps = new GPSTracker(ImageCaptureActivity.this);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();

            //get gps location coordinates
            if(gps.canGetLocation())
            {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                        + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //from latitude and longitude to address
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = null;
                try {
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    String tara = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String judet = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String oras = addresses.get(0).getSubLocality();
                    String adresa = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    System.out.println(tara + ", " + judet + ", " + oras + ", " + adresa + "\n");

                }
            } else {
                // Can't get location.
                // GPS or network is not enabled.
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings.
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Turn on GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent backIntent = new Intent(ImageCaptureActivity.this, Cont.class);
                startActivity(backIntent);
            }


            //TODO
            //GET DATE OF IMAGE
            String pathToFile = fileUri.getPath();
            File file = new File(pathToFile);
            if(file.exists()) {
                String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm-ss").format(
                        new Date(file.lastModified())
                );
                Toast.makeText(context, date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }



        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

/*
 * Here we restore the fileUri again
 */
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}
```

And helper methods:

```
    private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/*
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "file"
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " was not created");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFileName;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFileName = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFileName;
}

/*
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I want to send the photos on a REST WebService.

Comment: It will be very useful if you post some code so people can help you. Your question is too general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the edit!

First, your approach with saving the image and delete it is correct because it is not a good practice to keep the image in the memory.

Second,  I presume that you have a web REST service running on a web server. So if you want to upload the image, you have to do a HTTP call to the endpoint your server serves and with the proper request method. You can look [here](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) for more precise code example how to the exact call.

And finally, I advise you to do the heavy uploading job in foreground service so you can be sure that the OS will not kill your thread in the middle of the upload process.